# Kafka Streams join by key with complex condition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-join

I'm trying to join `KStream` with `GlobalKTable` by key, but with specific logic.

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, Integer> stream = builder.stream(inputTopic1); // key = "ABC"
    GlobalKTable<String, Integer> table = builder.globalTable(inputTopic2); // key = "ABC"

    stream.join(table, // join first by "ABC" = "ABC", then by "AB" = "AB", then by "A" = "A"
            (key, value) -> key,
            (valueLeft, valueRigth) -> {/* identify by which condition the join was performed */});
```

For example, if the key = "ABC", then:

- first, join by the complete key - i.e. "ABC" = "ABC"
- then, if not joined, join by the first two symbols (one symbol removed) - i.e. "AB" = "AB"
- finally, try to join by only one symbol - i.e. "A" = "A"

Additionally, it is required to know by which condition was the join performed - e.g., by 3 letters / by 2 letters / by 1 letter.

The question is, is it possible at all or should I search for a workaround? For example, make copies of GlobalKTable with corresponding keys (table with "ABC" key, one with "AB" key and one with "A" key) and perform 3 separate joins? Or maybe any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a series of left-joins against multiple tables would be possible (if you know of often you want to try the join). If the joins succeeds, you skip the next join. Using a combination of `leftJoin()` and `branch()` should allow you split the stream after each join into "joined" and "retry". At the end, you can `merge()` the different result streams together if you want.