# Latest Value from the KStream for a given key

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have KTable like below

```
KTable<productId1,productValue1>
KTable<productId2,productValue2>
KTable<productId3,productValue2>
```

Then i have `KStream<custId,productId>`, the productId is of any of productId1, productId2, productId3. I want to have the corresponding productValue.

The response would be like `KStream<custId, productValueN>`

If the KStream receives productId as productId2, then the response would be `KStream<custId, productValue2>`

How this could be possible?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326550/kafka-streams-join-by-key-with-complex-condition/59492835

Comment: I want to join the value of KStream with the key with KTable. Something like KeyValueJoin between two KStreams.

Comment: Just use `KStream#selectKey()` (or `map()`) before the join -- you need to set the join attribute as key before the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a `GlobalKTable` for products, and then joining the customers `KStream` with it as follows:

```
Serde<String> stringSerde = new Serdes.StringSerde();

StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

GlobalKTable<String, String> productsTable =
        streamsBuilder.globalTable(PRODUCTS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde),
                Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("products")
                        .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                        .withValueSerde(stringSerde));

streamsBuilder.stream(CUSTOMERS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde))
        .join(productsTable,
                (customerId, productId) -> productId,
                (productName1, productName2) -> productName2,
                Named.as("customersProducts"))
        .print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this KeyValueMapper with KTable. Like the way it is available below below for GlobalKTable

<br/>
**<GK, GV, RV> KStream<K, RV> join(GlobalKTable<GK, GV> var1, KeyValueMapper<? super K, ? super V, ? extends GK> var2, ValueJoiner<? super V, ? super GV, ? extends RV> var3);**
<br/>

May be selectKey what i should be using,<br/> Anyway Thanks

Comment: I've posted another answer for how to do this using a `KTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `KTable`s don't support `KeyValueMapper`s: `KStream`/`KTable` joins are performed strictly by comparing keys.  `GlobalKTable`s support this, making the whole process of joining much easier (see my other answer).

To get this to work then, you need to rekey the `customers` topic `KStream` to use the product ID, so that you can perform the join with the `products` topic `KTable`.

Once you've obtained the product name, you can rekey the resulting joined stream back to the customer ID.  For example:

```
// Key: product ID, value: product name
KTable<String, String> productsTable =
    streamsBuilder.table(PRODUCTS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde),
            Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("productsStore")
                    .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                    .withValueSerde(stringSerde));

streamsBuilder.stream(CUSTOMERS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde))
    // Key: customer ID, value: product ID
    .map((customerId, productId) -> KeyValue.pair(productId, String.format("%s|%s", customerId, productId)),
            Named.as("mapToProductIdAndCustomerIdProductId"))
    // Key: product ID, value: customer ID | product ID
    .join(productsTable, (customerIdProductId, productName) -> {
                String[] parts = customerIdProductId.split("\\|");
                String customerId = parts[0];
                return String.format("%s|%s", customerId, productName);
            },
            Joined.<String, String, String>as("customersProductsInnerJoin")
                    .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                    .withValueSerde(stringSerde))
    // Key: product ID, value: customer ID | product name
    .map((productId, customerIdProductName) -> {
        String[] parts = customerIdProductName.split("\\|");
        String customerId = parts[0];
        String productName = parts[1];
        return KeyValue.pair(customerId, productName);
    }, Named.as("mapToCustomerIdAndProductName"))
    // Key: customer ID, value: product name
    .print(Printed.toSysOut());
```